# creating an angular library and using it locally with my angular project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-library, pnpm

I'm trying to play with Angular 9, I want to create a project, and then to create a library project and start adding to it generic modules that I want to later publish on GitHub, and use these libraries locally in my project.

Here are the relevant dependencies:

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.0-rc.6
Node: 13.3.0
OS: MacOS 10.15.2
PNPM: 4.3.0
```

First I created my angular project with `ng new foo` and added to it angular material dependencies with `ng add @angular/material`

Then I created my library project with `ng new tuxin-ec --create-application=false`
and inside of it I executed `ng generate library animated-images --prefix=tuxin-ec`.

I intend to create like 15 common libraries to be used and published. is this the way to do it? just to do `ng generate library` for each one?

Currently under projects in the `tuxin-ec` project directory I have `animated-images` that contains a module, service and controller, I added the relevant code to the controller html and css.

I want to link `tuxin-ec` locally in my project.
So under `tuxin-ec` root directory I ran `pnpm link`
and under `foo` directory I ran `pnpm link tuxin-ec`.

Under `foo` in `node_modules` directory I also have tuxin-ec linked directory.

The problem is that I want to do `import {AnimatedImagesModule} from 'tuxin-ec` 
but it complains that it can't find `tuxin-ec`

what I was able to do is `import {AnimatedImagesModule} from 'tuxin-ec/dist/animated-images'`

But even then when I try to import `AnimatedImagesModule` in my project I would get an error that `class AnimatedImagesModule is not an angular module`.

Is there some way to achieve my intended results?

thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so I googled some for and I found the following wonderful tutorial: https://willtaylor.blog/complete-guide-to-angular-libraries/

and there I understood that I don't link my entire project, I link specific modules, which actually makes a lot of sense :)

so inside dist/animated-images directory I should have executed `npm link` and then in my project i should have done `npm link animated-images`. that's it! pretty simple!